# WebRTC & Chrome Vs Safari - How to make it work?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webrtc, html5-video

I'm creating a simple web-based video recorder. I got everything working on Chrome and then to my horror, started getting `mimeType not supported` error on Safari. After debugging, it looks like the entire problem is about using the right configuration in this line -

```
// Works in Safari, but not in Chrome. Tested only once
this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, {mimeType:'video/mp4;codecs=avc1'});

// Works in Chrome, but not in Safari.
this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, {mimeType:'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus'});
```

I've tried including `adapterJS`, but the problem doesn't go away.

The obvious choice here is to check the browser and then load the appropriate mimeType. However, I'm not sure if this will work across multiple platforms (Android, iOS, Windows, MacOS).

Is there any way to fix this and make videos work fine across all the browsers? Would appreciate your guidance. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not forced to specify codec, you could remove the second optionnal parameter to use default value (so no check of what is available).

Otherwise you could list what is available (a quick search show some example) and use codecs found.

Comment: Currently I've settled with
```
const mimeContent = window.MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/mp4;codecs=avc1') ? 'video/mp4;codecs=avc1' : 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus';
                        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, {mimeType: mimeContent});
```
Which works fine with the latest versions of Chrome and Safari. The problem is only with the older versions of Safari. Wish to know if there's a better approach to do this, or simply skipping the second parameter will work on both Chrome and Safari.